Не подключается клавиатура logitech k380 к Linux mint
Пробовал подключить её через графический интерфейс и через терминал, через графический интерфейс пишет, что она подключена, но не работает, а в терминале пишет, что не работает.
Информация о системе:
Kernel: 6.5.0-18-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A;  Desktop: Cinnamon 6.0.4 tk: GTK 3.24.33; wm: muffin; vt: 7; dm: LightDM 1.30.0; Distro: Linux Mint 21.3 Virginia;  base: Ubuntu 22.04 jammy;  Machine Type: Laptop; System: ASUSTeK product: TUF Gaming FX505DT_FX505DT
Вот логи подключения
[bluetooth]# trust F4:73:35:B3:03:E1
[CHG] Device F4:73:35:B3:03:E1 Trusted: yes
Changing F4:73:35:B3:03:E1 trust succeeded
[bluetooth]# pair F4:73:35:B3:03:E1
Attempting to pair with F4:73:35:B3:03:E1
[CHG] Device F4:73:35:B3:03:E1 Connected: yes
[agent] Passkey: 074397
[agent] Passkey: 074397
[agent] Passkey: 074397
[agent] Passkey: 074397
[agent] Passkey: 074397
[agent] Passkey: 074397
[agent] Passkey: 074397
[CHG] Device F4:73:35:B3:03:E1 Modalias: usb:v046DpB342d4201
[CHG] Device F4:73:35:B3:03:E1 UUIDs: 00001000-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device F4:73:35:B3:03:E1 UUIDs: 00001124-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device F4:73:35:B3:03:E1 UUIDs: 00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device F4:73:35:B3:03:E1 ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device F4:73:35:B3:03:E1 Paired: yes
Pairing successful
[CHG] Device F4:73:35:B3:03:E1 WakeAllowed: yes
[CHG] Device F4:73:35:B3:03:E1 ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device F4:73:35:B3:03:E1 Connected: no

Если пробую подключиться снова, то пишет
[bluetooth]# pair F4:73:35:B3:03:E1
Attempting to pair with F4:73:35:B3:03:E1
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AlreadyExists


А где после сопряжения connect F4:73:35:B3:03:E1?

Как и сказал @user207200, дело было в том, что после всего этого я не написал:
connect F4:73:35:B3:03:E1

